# Is the output of "Test the function" of a Google Cloud Function saved somewhere?

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform

I have returned the database address with username and password as the plain text output of a Cloud Function during testing. The idea was to see how the db URL looks like and where the error could be that made the connection fail. Bad idea of course. Is the result of "Test the function" in tab "Testing" logged anywhere? I could not find the exposed db URL in the logs of that Cloud Function, is it perhaps stored anywhere else? Should I change my password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not seen any logs of the return of the query since the question was asked. The only thing that may get logged is prints or loggings, but the return that is shown in the `Testing` tab itself does not get logged, it is just printed once in the output of the `Testing` tab.